# Material theme naming conventions

Tags: android, material-design

One of the built in templates for Android Studio will create the following themes:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base App Theme -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

In this instance `AppTheme.NoActionBar` is not explicitly specifying `AppTheme` as the parent. Does Android use naming conventions for this and implicitly inherit the theme in this case?

Comment: Have a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#Inheritance

Comment: @DavidMedenjak Feel free to post what I have as the answer so I can accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks, just go ahead and accept yours :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to David for pointing me to the documentation:

If you want to inherit from styles that you've defined yourself, you do not have to use the parent attribute. **Instead, just prefix the name of the style you want to inherit to the name of your new style, separated by a period.** For example, to create a new style that inherits the CodeFont style defined above, but make the color red, you can author the new style like this:

```
<style name="CodeFont.Red">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
</style>
```